# “I moved to the other place”

Tags: subordinate-clauses

I moved to the other place, and I wrote that I moved to the other place.

**“Someone moved.”**

Even though I wrote like this, it’s true that I wrote that I moved to the other place?

Otherwise, should I write all the sentence like this, even not changing words?

**”I moved to the other place.”**

Comment: I really don't understand what your question is.  "movement" by itself is not a sentence and doesn't convey any meaning.

Comment: @stangdon “There was movement.”

Comment: What are you trying to communicate by saying "someone moved"? The bank robbers said "nobody move!". Someone moved. The bank robbers started shooting.

Comment: If it was you who moved, why refer to yourself as 'someone'?

Comment: No, it is not clear that YOU moved to the other place by writing SOMEONE moved to the other place. No-one would ever know that you moved by reading that sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, my answer is:

Yes!! You can say "I moved" without specifying the location that you moved to.

If you write, "I moved," people will understand that you moved to another place.

(But of course you should say "I" instead of "someone" if you're talking about yourself.)